# Submit form not working when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I have a form and when the user clicks submit, I would like the form to hide and a thank you message to appear. Unfortunately with the code I have, it's not working and I can't figure out why. I think it might be something with the jQuery so I'd like to try and re-write this function using vanilla JS, but I'm not sure how.

It is the last part of the function, the if (empty.length), hide form, show thank you message that is causing me problems. Everything else is working fine, so its this function I would like to try and write in JavaScript, or try another way using jquery to make it work. The problem is it doesn't work in my code, but when I open this in a jsfiddle, it doesnt just hide the form it opens a new page and I get an error. I don't want the user to be directed to a new page, I just want the form to close and thank-you message to appear. I am very new to this so I apologize if my code is messy.

UPDATE: I really think the issue here is the jQuery, can I write this in plain JS and would that fix it?

```js
var $subscribe = $('#click-subscribe');
var $subscribeContent = $('#subscribe-content');
var $subscribeClose = $('#subscription-close');

$subscribeContent.hide();

$subscribe.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $subscribeContent.slideToggle();
});

$subscribeClose.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $subscribeContent.slideToggle();
})

var $form = $('#signup-form'),
  $signupForm = $('.form-show'),
  $formReplace = $('#thank-you');

$formReplace.hide();


$form.on('submit', function() {
  var empty = $(this).find("input, select, textarea").filter(function() {
    return this.value === "";
  });

  if (empty.length <= 0) {
    $signupForm.hide();
    $formReplace.show();
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="click-subscribe">Show / hide form</button>
<div id="subscribe-content">
  <div class="subscription-signup">
    <div class="subscription-close" id="subscription-close"></div>
    <div class="email-signup">
      <p class="cat-title subscription-text">lorem ipsum</p>
      <p class="subscription-text">lorem ipsum</p>
      <p class="subscription-text">lorem ipsum</p>

      <div class="subscription-form">
        <form id="signup-form" class="form-show" name="signup-form" method="post" action="${URLUtils.url('Newsletter-SubscribeMobile')}">
          <div class="form-row salutation header">
            <label for="salutation">Title</label>
            <div class="chzn-row valid salutation">
              <select id="title" name="title" class="chzn-global-select input-select optional required">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <option value="Mr">Mr.</option>
                <option value="Mrs">Mrs.</option>
                <option value="Ms">Ms.</option>
                <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-row required">
            <label for="firstname">
              <span aria-required="true">First Name</span>
              <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input class="input-text required" id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="" maxlength="500" autocomplete="off">
          </div>

          <div class="form-row required">
            <label for="lastname">
              <span aria-required="true">Surname</span>
              <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
            </label>
            <input class="input-text required" id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value="" maxlength="500" autocomplete="off">
          </div>

          <div class="form-row required">
            <label for="signup-email" style="display:none;">Email</label>
            <input class="header-signup-email" type="text" id="signup-email-header" name="signup-email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-row text-center">
            <input type="submit" name="signup-submit" id="signup-submit" class="subscribe-submit" value="Submit" />
          </div>
        </form>

        <div id="thank-you">
          <p>Thanks for subscribing!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you put all your relevant code into a jsfiddle? this would make it easier for us.

Comment: The issue that I am seeing is that if you go into the `empty.length <= 0` truth part of the if, you are not canceling the form submit, so the page is going to do a transfer to the action of your form.  Trying to show something extra there doesn't really make sense as the user is leaving the page they performed the submit on.

Comment: @Taplar I'm sorry I'm confused about what you mean. How would I fix that? I also tried to edit and hit ctrl+m but nothing happens.

Comment: But in regards to what I was talking about.  When you submit a form, unless you do something special to them, they will normally navigate away from the page.  How familiar are you with html and form behavior, if I might ask?

Comment: @KatherineMichelle where is your `jQuery` code placed in your html file.

Comment: @Srinu i'm working with a lot of files. When I place the jquery script in this specific file, then the form works BUT still navigates to a different page, and other stuff on the page (like a carousel) stops working. When I take the script out, the other jquery on the page works but my form doesn't work. Which is why I'm wondering if it would work if I used vanilla JS

Comment: I would encourage you to work through your logic issue first, rather than abandoning jQuery.  jQuery is just a library written in javascript to help smooth out javascript logic across different browsers and different browser versions.  But it's still javascript.  The important part is your logic.

Comment: @KatherineMichelle `submit()` method will take you to another page, if you don't want forward another then you need remove `from.submit` and use `ajax` which will not submit the page. 
Coming to `carousel` not working issue check once `jQuery*.js` files loaded in your page and order of loading because different versions of `jQuery` cause the issues.  
With vanilla JS you need to write lot of code to handle situation where you can reduce it using `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

I think some other javascript/jQuery code are making issues to run the codes, for simple solution make your code as plugin and called it like following.

create new `js` file called `validation.js`

```
(function($){
    $.fn.validation = function(){        
        var $subscribe = $('#click-subscribe');
        var $subscribeContent = $('#subscribe-content');
        var $subscribeClose = $('#subscription-close');

        $subscribeContent.hide();
        $subscribe.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $subscribeContent.slideToggle();
        });
        $subscribeClose.on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $subscribeContent.slideToggle();
        });

        var $form = $('#signup-form'), $signupForm = $('.form-show'), $formReplace = $('#thank-you'); $formReplace.hide();
       this.on('submit', function(e){
            var empty = $(this).find("input, select, textarea").filter(function() {
                return this.value === "";
            });
            if(empty.length == 0){
                $signupForm.hide();
                $formReplace.show();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });        
    }; 
})(jQuery);
```

Now, call the `validation.js` at the `head` like below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#signup-form').validation();
});
</script>
```

Comment: @KatherineMichelle, i have updated the answer, check it now